# Angular-slickgrid is not showing custom headermenu item text(Only headermenu item icon is visible)

Tags: javascript, angular, slickgrid

I am using angular-slickgrid in an angular application.I want to add more menuitems to headermenu.
Below is the code I am using:

```
 column.header = {
    menu: {
      items: [
        // add Custom Header Menu Item Commands at the bottom of the already existing internal custom items
        // you cannot override an internal command but you can hide them and create your own
        // also note that the internal custom commands are in the positionOrder range of 50-60,
        // if you want yours at the bottom then start with 61, below 50 will make your command(s) on top
        {
          iconCssClass: 'fa fa-question-circle',
          disabled: (column.id === 'effort-driven'), // you can disable a command with certain logic
          titleKey: 'GROUP', // use "title" as plain string OR "titleKey" when using a translation key
          command: 'group',
          positionOrder: 61
        }
      ]
    }
  };
```

On running the application, only icon is visible no text for the above headermenu item.Screen shot attached:
[image]

Comment: I am following the steps mentiond in the link
https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/blob/master/src/app/examples/grid-headermenu.component.ts 
still facing same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is most probably in the comment

```
titleKey: 'GROUP', // use "title" as plain string OR "titleKey" when using a translation key
```

`titleKey` is when you use translation and you most probably don't have that translation. You should just use `title` with a regular text and that should work

Comment: Yes that was my mistake, I should not comment title